# Cannot run Sonatype Nexus in local

Tags: exception, localhost, repository, nexus, sonatype

Steps to reproduce

1. Downloaded the nexus-3.3.0-01-win64.zip
2. Extract the zip file in D drive
3. cd D:/nexus-3.3.0-01-win64/nexus-3.3.0-01/bin
4. nexus.exe /run

   Expected result:

> Started Nexus Repository Manager 3.3.0-01

Actual result:

```
2017-06-15 10:41:53,104+0800 ERROR [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Failed to start    
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:326) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:244) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.3.7.v20160115]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:384) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.3.7.v20160115]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer$JettyMainThread.run(JettyServer.java:274) [org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap:3.3.0.01]
```

Comment: The port nexus has been configured to run on is in use by another program.  Edit sonatype-work/nexus3/nexus.properties and choose a different port for Nexus to listen on.

Comment: thanks a lot @rseddon, this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

> Answer already given in comments by [@rseddon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2166420/rseddon). Adding it here so
>   that the answer can be accepted.

`java.net.BindException` means that the process cannot listen on the given port as the port is already occupied (usually by an existing process).  In the case of nexus start up, it indicates that some other process is listening on this port.

You can either find that process and kill it. On MS Windows, this could be found out by running `netstat` and `tasklist` as follows (assuming port 8081 is where its trying to bind and the first command gives pid 2216):

```
netstat -ano | findStr "8081"
tasklist /fi "pid eq 2216"
```

Or you could **change the port nexus is trying to listen on**, which is specified in the file `<installDir>\sonatype-work\nexus3\nexus.properties`.